# VIM Editor: File Enconding and Line Endings

Tags: linux, vim, textmate

When saving files, these are my default settings in TextMate (Mac OS X):

File Encoding: UTF8 (recommended)
Line Endings: LF (recommended)

How can I set VIM to save files with the same file encoding and line endings as TextMate? I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
" Stick with the UTF-8 encoding.
if has('multi_byte')
  " Encoding used for the terminal.
  if empty(&termencoding)
    let &termencoding = &encoding
  endif

  " Encoding used in buffers, registers, strings in expressions, "viminfo"
  " file, etc.
  set encoding=utf-8

  " Encoding used for writing files.
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
endif

" Use both Unix and DOS file formats, but favor the Unix one for new files.
set fileformats=unix,dos
```

**NOTE:** The merit of the last line is that both formats are displayed correctly in Vim buffer. For example, if you'd remove `dos` from `fileformats`, then all the `dos` files that you would open in Vim from now on would be cluttered with `^M` symbols at line endings. This `^M` is nothing else, but `\r` which Vim, in this case, would fail to interpret properly. Therefore, it is strongly recommended to keep `fileformats` as shown above. Don't worry, any new files that you create will be using `unix` format by default (as stated in the comment above).

If you encounter some file with `dos` format and want to convert it into `unix`, then type the following:

```
:set ff=unix
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does that IF condition do? is it necessary?

Comment: It is checking whether Vim was compiled with **multibyte** feature (which includes Unicode support and more). You can type `:version` and search for `+multi_byte`. If it is present there, it means that Vim was compiled with **multibyte** feature, and this check will certainly pass. On the other hand, if you see `-multi_byte` there, it means the opposite (Unicode is not supported), and accordingly this check won't pass, which in turn prevents Vim from crashing/barking when loading your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Yes, I have that option (+multi_byte). Is it recommended to set both encoding and fileencoding to utf-8? I don't really understand the difference between them. When I create a file which one is used? And which one when I save it. Thank you!

Comment: Short comments already give you quite some information on the actual purpose of both `encoding` and `fileencoding`. I have no intention to rewrite Vim documentation here. `:h encoding` and `:h fileencoding` are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

The line endings are determined by the `'fileformat'` (actually used) and `'fileformats'` (what gets detected) options. If there's `unix` in there, you're fine; that represents `<LF>`. You can use `:help` on any of these to read more.

Your `'encoding'` should be set to `utf-8`, and that value should also appear in `'fileencodings'` (it does by default).

You can check the settings with (note the tailing `?` after the option name):

```
:set encoding?
```

To make permanent changes, put the `:set ...` commands into your `~/.vimrc`.

Note that you can also always override the settings, e.g.

```
:edit ++ff=unix ++enc=utf-8 myfile
```